# how to pass data to buttons through an array in swift

Tags: ios, database, swift

I am trying to fetch data from the database to a slide menu. I am using the following code for fetching the data and need to connect to buttons in the buttons present in the UI.

```
func fetchiingcontact()
    {
        var allusers:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        allusers = ModelManager.getInstance().getAlldrawerData()//Fetching contacts objects from Sqlite
        for var  i = 0 ; i < allusers.count ; i++
        {
            var userobject : user = user()
            userobject = allusers.objectAtIndex(i) as! user
            let contactobjectuser:UserContactsClass = UserContactsClass()


            let userdefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let ownuserid = userdefault.integerForKey("Userid")
            if(userobject.userid == ownuserid)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                contactobjectuser.firstName = userobject.firstName
                contactobjectuser.lastName = userobject.lastName
                contactobjectuser.profilePic = userobject.profilePic
                contactobjectuser.nickName = userobject.nickName


                usercontactslistarray.addObject(contactobjectuser)
               self.secondLabel.text = contactobjectuser.lastName
             self.userFlname.text = contactobjectuser.firstName
            }


        }
```

how do i connect the usercontactslistarray to the ui buttons by code as self.secondlabel.text is not working

Comment: Your doesn't seem to have anything to do with SQLite or getting the data. That part seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
self. userFlname.setText(contactobjectuser.lastName)
self.secondLabel.setText(contactobjectuser.lastName)
```

Comment: it gives an error value of type 'uilabel' has no settext member 'setText'

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = "Your Text"

yourButton.setTitle(string as String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: i have a label which is getting data from the sqlite db so i need to change the username every time a user logs in